# Field access in Python loop variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just saw the following syntax in a Python snippet, and I'm wondering what it means:

```
    for state.epoch in range(state.epoch, epochs):
        for state.batch in range(state.batch, batches_per_epoch):
```

I've never seen a field access in a loop variable.

Comment: It's assigning to `state.epoch` in each loop iteration. The range creates a range from the original `state.epoch` to `epochs`. At the end, `state.epoch` should equal `epochs - 1`.

Comment: You can use anything that can be assigned as the iteration variable. Why do you think a class attribute would be any different?

Comment: However, the inner loop is not going to work very well. On the second iteration of the outer loop, `state.batch` will already be equal to `batches_per_epoch-1`, so the loop won't do anything.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't `for state.batch in range(state.batch, state.batch + batches_per_epoch):`?